# Private key authentication has been deprecated from the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos

I got this error while trying to get the AWS regions using the "ec2-describe-regions"

```
Private key authentication has been deprecated from the CLI. Please refer to the following documentation for more details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-soap-api.html
```

But I have the latest version of AWS CLI tools (Version : 1.7.1.3 2014-09-01)

In my .bashrc file here is the configuration :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export EC2_BASE=/opt/ec2
export EC2_HOME=$EC2_BASE/tools
export EC2_URL=https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-west-1
export AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER=XXXXXXXXXXXX
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:$EC2_HOME/bin
```

So can anyone please help me to resolve this….. :)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-soap-api.html) of the EC2 CLI version > 1.6.13.0, the supported variables are `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`, not `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`.